# Table default font size

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have multiple tables in my document. By default they use "Normal" style for any texts inside. However, while I keep my paragraph font size 14, I want to use font size 12 inside tables by default (and thus apply it to all current and future tables in this document and change them on the go if I find the need to so). How can I make it happen?

Tweaking each and every table separately is not a good option. So I am looking for a way similar to editing default styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new style. Set its type to Table. Then set the formatting ie font, font size, color, which style the table should be based on, etc. Select "New documents based on this template". Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

Insert a new table. Go to Table Design -> Table Styles. Find the style you created earlier. It will be on the Custom section. Right-click on it and select Set as Default.

[image]

Select "All documents based on Normal.dotm templates?", click OK.

[image]

Newly inserted tables will be based on your custom style.

Comment: Remember to name your style. Another alternative is to create a "Quick Table" which is a building block.

Comment: How can I access this style now? It is neither on the ribbon nor in styles window (by right-bottom corner button). Also how can I make it apply itself by default for all future tables?

Comment: @Arctomachine Home -> Styles, click the arrow, when the Styles window open, click A+ to create a new style. The style should be applied automatically if you select "New documents based on this template".

Comment: I did it like this. The style is now even present in Manage styles window. But not on the ribbon. Not in the Styles window. And it is not applied to new tables as well (Insert - Tables).

Comment: @Arctomachine See edit.

Comment: Yes, now it works.